# how to search in table using jquery where pagination included?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Cant find data from another page of same table...

During the trime of search it will not consider data from another page which is in same table.

What should I have to change in script?

This is script which included externally:

```
     (function($){
    $.fn.tableSearch = function(options){
        if(!$(this).is('table')){
            return;
        }
        var tableObj = $(this),
            searchText = (options.searchText)?options.searchText:'Search: ',
            searchPlaceHolder = (options.searchPlaceHolder)?options.searchPlaceHolder:'',
            divObj = $('<div style="float:left;">'+searchText+'</div>'),
            inputObj = $('<input type="text" placeholder="'+searchPlaceHolder+'" />'),
            caseSensitive = (options.caseSensitive===true)?true:false,
            searchFieldVal = '',
            pattern = '';
        inputObj.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){
            searchFieldVal = $(this).val();
            pattern = (caseSensitive)?RegExp(searchFieldVal):RegExp(searchFieldVal, 'i');
            tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function(){
                var currentRow = $(this);
                currentRow.find('td').each(function(){
                    if(pattern.test($(this).html())){
                        currentRow.show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        tableObj.before(divObj.append(inputObj));
        return tableObj;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

This Script Included internally:

```
 <script>
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('table.search-table').tableSearch({
                    searchText:'Search Table',
                    searchPlaceHolder:'Search....'
                });




    });
    </script>
```

Comment: have you used datatables in this?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes!! I used datatables for getting data from database.. i fried select query in seach.php and it's working fine but  this code doesn't take result from another pages of same table and i used pagination here!!

Comment: U used datatable's pagination r custom pagination??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju custom pagination sir!

Comment: That is why it's not working... Maximum how many rows will come in the table??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju there are 5 rows in table! is there any possible solution in custome pagination ? i get 9 row then it will search data from 9 rows!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92217/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-chirag-senjaliya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion, what i would suggest you is to use data tables.

Check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/)

So you have to get all rows from database. Then populate in table.

Give `id` for that table, lets say `id="my-table`"

then add this script,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});// note pagination will be done by datatables
    });
</script>
```

This is suitable when you have less number of rows lets say, 1000 or 2000.
If it is more than that, datatables itself will support `ajax` functions to do this.

also for more information use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795054/How-to-use-jsfiddle-and-a-jQuery-Plugin-to-create) or [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)